# C++ boost log formater

Tags: c++, boost-log

I use boost v1.60 and I try to write a function to init and configure boost::log but I meet a weird behavior that I cannot explain. I call the following function.

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that my logger is define in a DLL and that I try to push the formater through the DLL API. The formater itself work perfectly if define and set from the inside of the DLL.

```
using formater_cb_t = boost::function<void(boost::log::record_view const&, boost::log::formatting_ostream& strm)>;
using filter_cb_t = boost::function<bool(const boost::log::attribute_value_set&)>;  
void AddCustomConsoleLogging(const formater_cb_t& formater_func, const filter_cb_t& filter_func) {
    auto pSink = boost::log::add_console_log(std::cout);
    pSink->set_formatter(formater_func);
    pSink->set_filter(filter_func);
  }
```

And I try to push 2 lambdas like below:

```
void AddCustomConsoleLogging(
      [](boost::log::record_view const& rcrd, boost::log::formatting_ostream& strm)-> void {
      namespace blog = boost::log;
      auto attr_set = rcrd.attribute_values();

      if (rcrd[boost::log::expressions::smessage]) {
        strm = *rcrd[boost::log::expressions::smessage] << ",";
      }
      if (attr_set["EventLevel"]) {
        strm << level_to_string(attr_set["EventLevel"].extract<Framework::EventLevel>().get());
        strm << ",";
      }
      },
      [](const boost::log::attribute_value_set& attr_set)->bool {return true; }
    );
```

The problem is with the **formater** lambda. If I use the following code to trigger some log line on the command line output, it failed with the assertion `log/utility/value_ref.hpp, line 150`. In fact I can run and print all the `EventLevel` or all the `message` but not the 2 things at the same time !

```
BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT(LoggerImpl, boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<EventLevel>)
const std::string buf = "test message !";
BOOST_LOG_SEV(LoggerImpl::get(), TRACE) << message;
```

Comment: Could you add a backtrace to show where the assert is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Since no backtrace is given, I cannot be sure exactly where the problem is. However, I can say that handling of the "EventLevel" attribute value is incorrect and may lead to the assertion failure you're seeing.

The `if (attr_set["EventLevel"])` check only tests if there as an attribute value named "EventLevel" in the log record, but it doesn't check its type. This means that the subsequent `extract<Framework::EventLevel>()` may return an empty value reference, which will trigger the assertion failure on `get`.

I am not sure that is what actually happens also because you haven't shown the complete code, and, in particular, the "EventLevel" is not added anywhere in the code you shown.

The correct way to test the attribute value presence is to check if the extracted value reference is not empty. The first check for `smessage` is doing it correctly, although inefficiently, by leveraging attribute keywords. You can do the same for "EventLevel" as well.

```
// Declare a keyword for the EventLevel attribute
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_event_level, "EventLevel", EventLevel)

void AddCustomConsoleLogging(
      [](boost::log::record_view const& rcrd, boost::log::formatting_ostream& strm)-> void {
      auto msg = rcrd[boost::log::expressions::smessage];
      if (msg) {
        strm << *msg << ",";
      }

      auto lvl = rcrd[a_event_level];
      if (lvl) {
        strm << level_to_string(*lvl);
        strm << ",";
      }
      },
      [](const boost::log::attribute_value_set& attr_set)->bool {return true; }
    );
```